# Google Cloud SDK-based Maven plugin is forcing itself to update and then failing, when cloud sdk is up to date

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I'm making a Java program which will be deployed to the Google App Engine and I'm using the Cloud SDK maven plugin version 2.4.0 to deploy to the GAE. However when I run `mvn package appengine:deploy` the cloud SDK will say its current version is 321.0.0 and needs to update to 327.0.0. The update will then fail with the error:
`ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) Access is denied: [C:\Users\jamie\AppData\Local\Google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk.staging\platform\kuberun_licenses\LICENSES.txt]`

However when I just run `gcloud components update` I get the result of `All components are up to date.`

Anyone know why this may be happening or how to fix it?

EDIT: As a work-around I found you can force the maven plugin to use a specific version of the sdk by using `<cloudSdkVersion>321.0.0</cloudSdkVersion>`. I'm still very curious to know why this occurred though

Comment: Have you checked if the account running maven has permissions to access the `C:\Users\jamie\AppData\Local\Google` folder and it's subfolders?

Comment: @RafaelLemos Yes I have, pretty sure it makes the LICENSES.txt file during the update process as its in a staging subfolder. Tried deleting the file and then updating and it just replaced it and then said it couldn't access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manged to fix this by deleted the whole `C:\Users\jamie\AppData\Local\Google\ct4j-cloud-sdk` folder as this forces the plugin to redownload a fresh SDK.

The error occurs as the plugin uses its onw auto managed SDK rather than the one which is user managed.